# JWindow won't display ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

I am wondering why my JWindow won't display my image. I have this code:

```
JWindow window = new JWindow();
JPanel jp = new JPanel();
JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("GenericApp.png"));
jp.add(l);
window.add(jp);
window.setBounds(500, 150, 300, 200);
window.setVisible(true);
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
window.setVisible(false);
```

**EDIT:** My code is now (Back to original):

```
final JWindow window = new JWindow();
JPanel jp = new JPanel();
JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Asset.class.getResource("GenericApp.png")));
jp.add(l);
window.add(jp);
window.setBounds(500, 150, 300, 200);
window.setVisible(true);
try{
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}catch(InterruptedException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
window.setVisible(false);
```

Yes, I decided to use `Thread.sleep()`. My jar executes from /Users/thomasokeeffe/Desktop/eclipse/AI/AI, and that is where the picture is. I still get a blank JWindow when I launch. And `System.out.println(new File("GenericApp.png").exists());` returns true.

**Yet another edit** will it be easier for me if I put the picture in the jar file? One of the weirdest things is that when I run the jar not in the app and put the picture in the working directory, it still shows a blank rectangle.......

**EDIT** By now I have tried using a URL, and debugging by getting the user.dir system property. I have these two line of code for getting the picture now (the picture is in the same package as the class):

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("GenericApp.png");
JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(url));
```

I have also tried using an InputStream:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("GenericApp.png");
Image image = null;
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(is);
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Thread.sleep(5000);` probably isn't going to help.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for  more details.  Does the window actually show up at all?

Comment: I couldn't figure out where to put the code, before, after or in the timer.

Comment: Part of the code goes in the `Timer`, in particular, the `setVisible(false)`.  Where is the image stored (within context to the projects source)?

Comment: I have my jar in an app. The pic is in the java folder with the jar

Comment: Assuming that the image is in the same directory as the Jar AND the program is executed from the same location as the Jar, then you image should load.  Try using `JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("GenericApp.png"))))` instead, which will throw an `IOException` if the image can't be read

Comment: Add `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` to your code and verify that the path is the same as the location of the Jar and the image.  If that works, you can also try and using `System.out.println(new File("GenericApp.png").exists());` to verify that the file exists within the current execution location

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.  And this general topic of loading images using `ImageIcon` (which gives no feedback, beyond the image not appearing as to loading success) comes up every couple of days, if not daily.

Comment: I''' try it. Thanks!

Comment: still blank. I think the problem is with the image icon.

Comment: I am going to make a new question with the Title: Eclipse Java application can't find resources.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is in your jar or generally in your classpath, you can get a hold of it by

```
getClass().getResource(resourcePath);
```

Where resource path is rooted at the roots of your classpath.

For instance, an image in the same dir as your class would be

```
new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("GenericApp.png")));
```

Comment: *"I have my jar in an app. The pic is in the java folder with the jar "* - So, based on that, I would say, no, it's not in the Jar...

Comment: An advantage to this method is that you will get an NPE when the image is not found, unlike the approach you are using now which fails silently.

Comment: `ImageIO.read` will also throw a `IOException` which is better then `ImageIcon`, but if the resource doesn't exist in the Jar file, it won't solve the problem...

Comment: @MadProgrammer it's kind of hard to interpret what exactly the poster meant by that. All that matters really is that the image is somewhere relative to the classpath roots. For a self-contained app, that's just-about always the case. Many build systems will generate a resources dir specifically for that.

Comment: And if it's not?  Like if the execution context is not the same as the source location of the Jar?  It won't solve the problem

Comment: @MadProgrammer ImageIO.read doesn't solve the 'my app can't find its resources' any better than what the poster has, really. Which is the fundamental problem.

Comment: But, `ImageIO` works for both embedded resources and external resources, it will at least provide better information to the root cause of the problem

Comment: What do you mean if it's not? Your app has a resource.  There is a standard way to solve this - which is class.getResource. If you don't want to do that, use an absolute pathname but that's a) fragile b) not any better whether passing a direct path or going through ImageIO.

Comment: But that's my point, what if the resource is within the class path of the application but on the file system?  If the current working directory isn't the same as the location of the Jar file, Java won't be able to find the file.  Yes, this is why I would recommend using an embedded resource

Comment: If the resource can't be found relative to the classpath, it is really not a sane way to define an application resource. You have to construct the path yourself, somehow. ImageIO or new File, etc, doesn't directly help you there - you have a fundamentally different problem. The base problem here seems to be 'my app can't find its resources'. The general solution to that ls the getResource method on Class.

Answer (score -1):

Gui code works with event calls. While your function is executing in the main thread nothing will change on screen. Actual changes on screen are done between calls to your code. This means that your functions should be finished as quickly as possible.

So to get something to show you need to return.

To queue some code to execute later you can use a javax.swing.Timer:

```
JWindow window = new JWindow();
JPanel jp = new JPanel();
JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("GenericApp.png"));
jp.add(l);
window.add(jp);
window.setBounds(500, 150, 300, 200);
window.setVisible(true);
Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener(){
    void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        window.setVisible(false);
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(false);//only do this once
timer.start();
```

Comment: it gives an error: remove arguments to match Timer()

Comment: @TheWrenchintheSystem `import javax.swing.Timer;` there is another timer class in the standard library that likes conflicting with the swing timer.

Comment: the main program appears before the splash window disappears.

Comment: While I prescribe to the idea of using a Swing `Timer`, you're assuming that the OP has started the program within it's context.  In response to asking whether the window was been displayed or not, the OP responded *"yes but it is blank"*, which would suggest that they are not running within in the EDT.  This also doesn't solve the issue of the image not been displayed